# How to obtain the entry value on button click in a tkinter app with multiple pages?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to obtain the current entry value from the `Page2` of the Tkinter app when the button `Run` is clicked.

Please help!

My codes:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import RAISED


LARGEFONT =("Verdana", 35)

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):

    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # __init__ function for class Tk
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # creating a container
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        container2 = tk.Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=2)
        container2.pack(side="bottom",fill="both", expand=True)
        container2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        def runStadiumpy():
            pass
            #get all entry value from page 2


        runButton = ttk.Button(container2, text="Run", command=runStadiumpy)
        runButton.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=5)

        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {}

        # iterating through a tuple consisting
        # of the different page layouts
        for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2):

            frame = F(container, self)

            # initializing frame of that object from
            # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with
            # for loop
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    # to display the current frame passed as
    # parameter
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

# first window frame startpage

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # label of frame Layout 2
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Startpage", font = LARGEFONT)

        # putting the grid in its place by using
        # grid
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 1",
        command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        ## button to show frame 2 with text layout2
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 2",
        command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)




# second window frame page1
class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Page 1", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="StartPage",
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        # putting the button in its place
        # by using grid
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 2",
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)




# third window frame page2
class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Page 2", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 1",
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        # button to show frame 3 with text
        # layout3
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Startpage",
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        lbl1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Question:")
        lbl1.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        entry1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        entry1.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        entry1.insert(0,"abc")


# Driver Code
app = tkinterApp()
app.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference for your entry in class `Page2`, like:

```
class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        ......

        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry1.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.entry1.insert(0,"abc")
```

Due to you save those frames in your `self.frames`, you could visit `Page2` by `self.frames[Page2]`.After add a reference for your entry, use `self.frames[Page2].entry1` to get the entry directly.

So after add the code above, use this code below in function `runStadiumpy()`:

```
def runStadiumpy():
    print(self.frames[Page2].entry1.get())
```

And you will get the content in the Page2

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you:-

```
def runStadiumpy():
    value = entry1.get()
    return value
```

Comment: But `entry1` is not defined in the class `tkinterApp`!

Comment: Try writing that function block into the class `Page2`

Comment: Indeed! But I want this feature to be available across pages.

Comment: You can navigate to Page2 class and then extract the values from there. Try using `var = self.frames[Page2] ` in **runStadiumpy()**

Comment: And then `var.entry1.get()` to grab the value.